# Interrupt network connection/cause lag

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking to interrupt network connection and or cause lag to the point where nothing will go through, basically clogging the line.

I'm making a "lag-switch" you could say.

I've tried using Windows Firewall API and blocking an application but that causes an instant disconnect rather than the lag I was hoping to achieve.

Original idea was to only block one application but I'm not sure how doable that is unless I can limit the bandwidth usage of said application so the latency would skyrocket. Blocking the entire local connection would be plan B.

Anything that immediately closes the connection will disconnect instantly.

I havn't tried anything else than blocking applications via firewall.

If someone could give me a kick in the back it would be real helpful!

Comment: Proxy server.  Proxy server.

Comment: @MartinJames The application I'm attempting to block/cause lag for is a third party program that I have no control of in any way really. I can't run it through a proxy. Or could you elaborate?

Comment: I hope you aren't going to use this on AoE II.

Comment: @9000 Heh, god no. This will not have an impact on any other person. I'm not that malicious :)

Comment: If you drop the packets at the firewall instead of blocking them it should at least cause a timeout instead of an immediate disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that sending tons of UDP packets to any address (say, 127.0.0.1) in a `while` loop with no delay causes immense network lag, but I haven't tested this in Windows.

Comment: I couldn't achieve the results I was hoping for with this. It had no effect, at least what I tried. And I spammed good.